# AudioFocusChangeListener cannot listen

Tags: android, audio, listener, multimedia, android-audiomanager

I encounter a problem using the AudioFocusChangeListener, but still cannot listen to the audio focus change. Could someone help me find the reasons? Here is what I do:

1. In my FM app, when FM starts in startFM, I place `requestAudioFocus()` to get resources:

   ```
   int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mAudioFocusListener, AudioManager.STREAM_FM,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
   if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
       Log.d(LOGTAG, "Successfull to request audioFocus listener");
   } else {
       Log.d(LOGTAG, "Failure to request focus listener");
   }
   ```
2. When quitting the App in `onDestroy()`, I used `abandonAudioFocus()` to release resouces.
3. The member variable `mAudioFocusListener` is as follows:

   ```
   private OnAudioFocusChangeListener mAudioFocusListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
   public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
       switch (focusChange) {
           case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
               Log.v(LOGTAG, "AudioFocus: received AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS, turning FM off");

               if (isFmOn()) {
                   fmOff();
               }
               break;
           case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
               Log.v(LOGTAG, "AudioFocus: received AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK");

               if (isFmOn()) {
                   Log.d(LOGTAG, "AudioFocus: FM is on, turning off");
                   mute();
                   stopFM();
               }
               break;
           case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
               Log.v(LOGTAG, "AudioFocus: received AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT");

               if (isFmOn()) {
                   Log.d(LOGTAG, "AudioFocus: FM is on, turning off");
                   mute();
                   stopFM();
               }
               break;
           case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
               Log.v(LOGTAG, "AudioFocus: received AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN");

               if (isFmOn()) {
                   Log.d(LOGTAG, "AudioFocus: FM is off, turning back on");
                   unMute();
                   startFM();
               }
               break;
           default:
               Log.e(LOGTAG, "Unknown audio focus change code " + focusChange);
       }
   }
   };
   ```
4. According to the log, it prints "Successfull to request audioFocus listener", but doesn't print any `AudioForcus` change log when alarm is on or other audio-changed events. Could anyone figure out what is wrong with it?
5. On the other hand, I place log in AudioService.java and AudioManger.java, where in AudioService.java, requestAudioFocus():
    if (!mFocusStack.empty() && (mFocusStack.peek().mFocusDispatcher != null)) {

   ```
          try {  

               mFocusStack.peek().mFocusDispatcher.dispatchAudioFocusChange(  

                        -1 * focusChangeHint, // loss and gain codes are inverse of each other  

                        mFocusStack.peek().mClientId);  // This doesn't excute

           } catch (RemoteException e) {  

               Log.e(TAG, " Failure to signal loss of focus due to "+ e);  
               e.printStackTrace();  

            }  

        }
   ```
6. in AudioManager.java, Here doesn't excute either:
       private IAudioFocusDispatcher mAudioFocusDispatcher = new IAudioFocusDispatcher.Stub() {

   ```
   public void dispatchAudioFocusChange(int focusChange, String id) {  

       Message m = mAudioFocusEventHandlerDelegate.getHandler().obtainMessage(focusChange, id);  

        mAudioFocusEventHandlerDelegate.getHandler().sendMessage(m);  

    }
   ```

That's all my question. Could anybody tell me why this listener cannot listen to alarm events and other audiofocus-changed events? By the way, how could I successfully listen to the events? Maybe I missed some step or used a incorrect way? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private class MyService extends Service implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        switch (focusChange) {
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                Log.e(TAG, "AudioFocus: received AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS, turning FM off");
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                Log.e(TAG, "AudioFocus: received AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK");
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                Log.e(TAG, "AudioFocus: received AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT");
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                Log.v(TAG, "AudioFocus: received AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN");
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Unknown audio focus change code " + focusChange);
        }
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and...

```
mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(new MyService(), AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

Its works for me.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that music and FM conflicts. I solve it by modifying music. The music app have been taken the focus after it interrupts. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

DeerCoder,

I believe that if you are requesting the audio focus for the type AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, you would only receive events affecting this specific audio stream.

```
mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(new MyService(), AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

The alarms and notifications are managed on separate audio stream such as AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, AudioManager.STREAM_RING, etc...